# React JS/React Native: passing parameter(s) to a pre-defined event handler in a render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm rendering some view in react native. From what read, we should avoid defining a new function or using bind inside a render method for performance reason. So in this case, I have a flat list, each list item is rendered as a `TouchableNativeFeedback` which invokes `handleOnPress` on press. Sample code is below.

```
<FlatList
    data={items}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => item.id}
    renderItem= {this.renderSingleItem}
    extraData={this.state}
/>
```

and

```
renderSingleItem = ({item}) => (
    <TouchableNativeFeedback onPress={this.handleOnPress}>
        <View>
            <Text>bla bla bla</Text>
        </View>
    </TouchableNativeFeedback>
);
```

Here I'm having trouble passing parameter to `handleOnPress`, specially I need to pass `item.id` from `TouchableNativeFeedback` to `this.handleOnPress`. In the example here https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/ , it uses `ListItem` and author said

```
// handleClick still expects an id, but we don't need to worry
// about that here. Just pass the function itself and ListItem
// will call it with the id.
```

which is really confusing.

My questions are

1) How does `ListItem` pass `id` to `handleClick` in example https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props ?

```
<ListItem key={item.id} item={item} onItemClick={handleClick} />
```

Is it because it passes the props `key` by default? It seems a trivial question but I cant find `ListItem` doc on react native page, maybe it has been deprecated like `ListView`

2) How do I pass parameter to pre-defined event handler in a generic react element such as `TouchableNativeFeedback`'s `onPress`, if I don't want to define a new anonymous function (e.g., `onPress={() => this.handleClick(someParam)}`) or use bind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. How does ListItem pass id to handleClick in example https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props ?

follow the post. I see the answers you want

```
var ListItem = React.createClass({
  render() {
    // Don't need a bind here, since it's just calling
    // our own click handler
    return (
      <li onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.props.item.name}
      </li>
    );
  },

  handleClick() {
    // Our click handler knows the item's id, so it
    // can just pass it along.
    this.props.onItemClick(this.props.item.id);
  }
});
```

`handleClick` function's params do not have `id` but it's content call `id` from component props

> 2. How do I pass parameter to pre-defined event handler in a generic react element such as TouchableNativeFeedback's onPress, if I don't want to define a new anonymous function (e.g., onPress={() => this.handleClick(someParam)}) or use bind

Just create a new component like ListItem above and change the render method

```
renderSingleItem = ({item}) => (
    <ListItem item={item} />
);
```